# Is there a way to verify if a post in Facebook has been deleted trough Graph Api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to verify if a post has been deleted using Graph API?

Comment: Your question is lacking some info, do you actually have some post-id to begin with? If so https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/post/

Comment: Not really. You will get an "Unsupported GET request" error from the API in such cases; but that is the same error you get for example if your app simply does not have the rights to read an existing post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By what information you've given. I would suggest you look at this doc for info. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/post/

It has some variables like "is_published", "is_visible" and other.

So an answer to your question is, maybe and yes.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I haven seen the documentation before, unfortunetly, these variables don't help me to know if a post have been delete